# How is the IV embedded in an encrypted file when you do not indicate it?

Tags: aes, openssl, md5

Suppose I encrypt with a key "1234" a file containing "abcd" with:

`openssl enc -iv BABA -aes128 -in file.txt -out file.enc -p`

I get:

```
salt=1B929D9049534D22
key=0326A1E8F4875B26FE2D04E02425C5AD
iv =BABA0000000000000000000000000000
```

So far so good.

I am able to decrypt the file with:

`openssl enc -d -aes128 -iv BABA -in file1.enc -out file1.dec.txt -p`

And obviously I get the same salt, key and iv as before.

First question is: in which sense "0326A1E8F4875B26FE2D04E02425C5AD" is the "key"?

Which is its relation with my key "1234"? (It looks an md5 hash. But... of what?)

Let's go on.
Now I do the same (same plaintext, same key) without providing the iv:

`openssl enc -aes128 -in file.txt -out file2.enc -p`

I get:

```
salt=237F07334625A768
key=F746D2B53EB82F7129BAEB2FCE2C310F
iv =BA28DBA00442BD4BACEBCAE7C01BA412
```

Now I decrypt with:

`openssl enc -d -aes128 -in file2.enc -out file2.dec.txt -p`

and I get the same WITHOUT providing the iv!

```
salt=237F07334625A768
key=F746D2B53EB82F7129BAEB2FCE2C310F
iv =BA28DBA00442BD4BACEBCAE7C01BA412
```

Now, while I can see the salt in the encrypted file and I provide the key to the program, I do not type the iv nor I can see the iv in the encrypted file.

Therefore the second question is: how does the decryption program know the iv which is needed to decrypt the file? Or, to put it differently, if the iv is embedded in the encrypted file (like the salt is), how is it done?

Answer (score 1):

The key and IV are both calculated from the password using a PBKDF. In the case of OpenSSL the method used is `EVP_BytesToKey`. This is a function akin to PBKDF1 which doesn't use many iterations. The salt is an input parameter to the PBKDF. It makes sure that the key and IV are always different, even if you use the same password.

You can have a look at the source code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11786924/589259) to get an idea how the key and IV derivation takes place (`EVP_BytesToKey` is not described that well, it is a proprietary mechanism within OpenSSL).

Basically, during encryption:

```
openssl_encrypt(password: string, plaintext: bytes): bytes
{
    salt:bytes = random(8) # 8 bytes = 64 bits
    iterations:int = 1
    key:bytes, iv:bytes = pbkdf(password, iterations, salt)
    ciphertext:bytes = encrypt_aes_cbc_pkcs7padding(key, iv, plaintext)
    encoded_ciphertext:bytes = "Salted__" | salt | ciphertext
    return encoded_ciphertext
}
```

and this is decryption:

```
openssl_decrypt(password:string, encoded_ciphertext:bytes)
{
    salt:bytes = take(encoded_ciphertext, from: 8, size: 8) # 8 bytes = 64 bits
    ciphertext:bytes = take(encoded_ciphertext, from: 16, size: sizeof(encoded_ciphertext - 16)
    iterations:int = 1
    key:bytes, iv:bytes = pbkdf(password, iterations, salt)
    plaintext:bytes = decrypt_aes_cbc_pkcs7padding(key, iv, ciphertext)
    return plaintext
}
```

Comment: I must be missing something: IV is needed to have different ciphertexts for each encryption with the same plaintext. Now, if the recipients gets the IV from the key, the same key gives the same IV and the same ciphertext. 
A solution I can imagine is to compute the IV from the key AND from the Salt. That would guarantee the uniqueness of the ciphertext AND the recovery of the plaintext by the recipient.

If that is the real solution, I wonder what exactly the algorithm from (Key, Salt) to (IV) is and how the result is embedded in the ciphertext.

Comment: Could you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11786924/589259)? So the key and IV are directly derived from salt and password. If the salt and password combination are unique (and they will if just the salt is random and large enough) then **both** the key and IV are different for each encryption. That the IV is randomized is not even a real requirement, but I guess it is nice (note though that getting the IV from the EVP_BytesToKey or PBKDF2  is not efficient, so it's not best practice).

Comment: If, as you probably correctly affirm, the IV is computed from salt and password, wouldn't that violate the basic idea that the IV must (or can?) be a public datum?

Comment: The IV doesn't need to be public. And it can be any value, including a constant value, if they resulting key is different each time (which would be the case for the same password if the salt value is changed).